# Python - Threading with PyQt

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

I'm new on the use of threads on Python and please, I need help on this.

I'm using PyQt and when I use a loop, the main window is frozen until the loop finish.

I read about threading on python and it seem a solution but I don't know if use of threading that I wrote on my code it's well.

This is an example of my code.

```
from Window import *
import sys, threading

class Window(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Window()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.button_download,   QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), start)

print("I'm the main thread")

def start():
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=process)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()

def process():
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        print("I'm the thread:", i)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Window()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining the thread right away. If you want it to run on background, then remove the line

```
t1.join()
```